# Eclipse Plugin for custom Strg+Click hook

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse for Java has the convenient feature of jumping to the definition of a class or method by clicking on a usage while holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-key.

I want to implement a similar functionality for the following usecase:
We have an annotation taking the path of a yaml-file as a parameter like this:

```
@MyAnnotation("myYamlFile.yaml")
```

Clicking on the filename while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (or some other key or combination) should open the file in an editor (the path is relative to a specified root path, which is on the classpath). Obviously selecting the filename and performing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (for "Open Resource") would work too, but since it'll be a very common usecase to jump between the Java and the yaml file, I want to look into making it even simpler.

My plan is to write a plugin for this. Before I start, I wanted to ask, if there's a simpler or better solution, maybe an existing plugin, which can be configured to be used for my purpose. Does anyone have experience with something similar, who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: STRG is German for what the Americans call the CTRL key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out quite easy to write an Eclipse plugin for it.

All I needed to do was implementing `org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.IHyperlink` and `org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.IHyperlinkDetector`.

http://codeandme.blogspot.co.at/2014/06/adding-hyperlink-detectors-to-editors.html